LVM2 - non-root VG LV not activated on reboot
One of our physical Ubuntu server has,
3 VGs in total - rootvg, 2 non-rootvgs(appvg1 & appvg2). Rootdisk is local HDD and both appvgs uses multipath disk (one disk each). appvg1 has filesystem that will mount during boot and appvg2 just has LV that will be mapped to KVM VM.
Ubuntu has both multipath-tools & multipath-tools-boot pkgs installed
On every reboot, all 3 vgs are activated, but appvg2 LV is not activated.
Using default LVM2 Event based activation using pvscan systemd units.
I'm confused why would VG becomes active but not LV (appvg2/lv)
tried removing multipath-tool-boot, but system ends up in single user mode. Tried updating Initramfs, no improvement. lvm configuration is unchanged, factory default, multipath is configured for vendor recommendation.

Just to be clear, does it work correctly when you activate it manually? Are there any relevant log messes in the system log?

yes, it works perfectly when manually activated with vgchange -ay command. No errors recorded in syslog.

LVM has a configuration file in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf which lets you define what VGs can be activated. in activation clause you can find this:
activation {
# more stuff removed from this snippet

# Configuration option activation/volume_list.
        # Only LVs selected by this list are activated.
        # If this list is defined, an LV is only activated if it matches an
        # entry in this list. If this list is undefined, it imposes no limits
        # on LV activation (all are allowed).
        #
        # Accepted values:
        #   vgname
        #     The VG name is matched exactly and selects all LVs in the VG.
        #   vgname/lvname
        #     The VG name and LV name are matched exactly and selects the LV.
        #   @tag
        #     Selects an LV if the specified tag matches a tag set on the LV
        #     or VG.
        #   @*
        #     Selects an LV if a tag defined on the host is also set on the LV
        #     or VG. See tags/hosttags. If any host tags exist but volume_list
        #     is not defined, a default single-entry list containing '@*'
        #     is assumed.
        #
        # Example
        # volume_list = [ "vg1", "vg2/lvol1", "@tag1", "@*" ]
        #
        # This configuration option does not have a default value defined.
        volume_list = [ "vg00", "vg01" ]

# more stuff removed from this snippet
}

In this example vg00 and vg01 is activated on boot. Make sure it's not specified at all or specify all VGs you want and then all VGs you care about should be activated on boot. Make sure you regenerate initramfs before rebooting.

thanks for the answer, we haven't defined the parameter at all, no customization done on LVM. Since we got few different VGs for each server (this issue is occuring on all the servers), I don't know if we can define this parameter for each server, maintainability is going to be a problem.
root@testhost:~# lvmconfig --type full activation/volume_list
root@testhost:~#
